# how to write , select clause subquery with spring data jpa?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jpql

**What I have**
 1. I am working on spring boot project.
 2. Following are two domain

a)

```
@Entity
@Table(name="oc_country")  
public class Country {  
    @Id  
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)  
    @Column(name="country_id", nullable=false, length=11)  
    private int countryId;  
    @Column(name="name",nullable=false,length=128)  
    private String name;  
    @Column(name="iso_code",nullable=false,length=2)  
    private String isoCode;  
    @Column(name="phonecode",nullable=false,columnDefinition="int(5)")  
    private int phoneCode;          
}
```

b)

```
@Entity  
public class ExchangeCountry{  
    @Id    
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)    
    private Long id;    
    @Column(name="country_id", nullable=false, length=11)    
    private int countryId;    
    private String fiatCurrency;    
    private boolean isDeleted=false;    
    @Column()     
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)    
    private Date createdDate = new Date();    
    @Column()     
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)  
    private Date updatedDate = new Date();  
    private Boolean isGlobalExchange=false;  

}
```

3. using mysql as database
4. I am getting result, when i am writing following mysql query
   Query:-> `select ex.country_id, (select name from oc_country c where c.country_id=ex.country_id) as countryName from exchange_country ex;`

**What I Want**
 1. How to write select clause subquery with JpaRepository( spring data jpa) in two entity?
 2. Is there any way to write above mysql query from jpa( spring data jpa) or other concept?

Thanks

Comment: Please use correct formatting.

Comment: @JimGarrison, I have added formatting

Comment: JPQL does not support use of subqueries in the SELECT clause. Some JPA vendors do (e.g DataNucleus JPA) but that is then non-portable.